Remove only consecutive blanks from VSTACK output
I often VSTACK columns and remove empty results with FILTER like so:
FILTER(VSTACK(<filtered_column_1>;<filtered_column_2>);
VSTACK(<filtered_column_1>;<filtered_column_2>)<>0)

But I've come accross a case in which I actually want to keep blanks that are not consecutive.
Unfiltered VSTACK output:
1
2
<blank>
<blank>
<blank>
2
2
3
<blank>
3

Desired filtered VSTACK output:
1
2
<blank>
2
2
3
<blank>
3

It should technically be easy comparing each value to the previous one, but my problem is that I don't know how to reference the VSTACK output columns for comparison in the FILTER "include" argument, specially considering the columns I'm feeding as arguments to the VSTACK are not referenceable columns but rather filtered columns themselves.
FILTER(VSTACK(<filtered_column_1>;<filtered_column_2>);
<what do I do here in the "include" argument?>)

Any ideas?

Then first and last <Blank> should be remain in output. They are not consecutive.

Yes, I can remove them with other formulas. I'll remove it for clarity.

Try my answer please.

You could do something like: =LET(d;VSTACK(<filtered_column_1>;<filtered_column_2>);crit;VSTACK(TAKE(d;1)<>"";(DROP(d;1)<>"")+(DROP(d;-1)<>""));FILTER(d;crit))

Try the following formula-
=LET(x,VSTACK("",1,2,"","","",2,2,3,""),
z,MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),LAMBDA(y,IF(AND(INDEX(x,y)="",INDEX(x,y-1)=""),FALSE,TRUE))),
FILTER(x,z))

Replace VSTACK("",1,2,"","","",2,2,3,"") with your VSTACK() formula.


Works! Thank you! Did not even know there was a MAP funcion in Excel. It seems to only work for single column outputs of VSTACK, but I'll adapt it from there. Thanks!

Something like:
=FILTER(<arr>,SCAN(0,<arr>="",LAMBDA(x,y,(x+y)*y))<2)


Remove Consecutive Blanks From Column

Something similar was suggested by Rory in your comments.

=LET(fc,A2:A11,sc,C2:C11,
    st,VSTACK(fc,sc),
    d,IF(st="","",st),
    dn,d="",
    ds,VSTACK(FALSE,DROP(dn,-1)),
    r,FILTER(d,dn*ds=0),
    r)



If you don't need step d (preventing blanks from showing as zeros), put the st formula in d and remove st.

Replace the bottom-most r with any other variable to see what it holds.

You could create a Lambda function in the Name Manager, e.g. RemoveCB using the following formula:
=LAMBDA(array,LET(dn,array="",FILTER(array,dn*VSTACK(FALSE,DROP(dn,-1))=0)))


Then you could utilize it on your stacked column, e.g. H2# (in the screenshot), with the following formula:
=RemoveCB(H2#)




Stacking up for fun, similar to JvdV's logic,
=LET(
    data, A1:B10,
    stacked, VSTACK(INDEX(data, , 1), INDEX(data, , 2)),
    filtered, FILTER(
        stacked,
        LEN(TRIM(stacked & VSTACK(DROP(stacked, 1), "")))
    ),
    IF(LEN(filtered), filtered, "")
)


